# SmartTarget FredHopper Date/Trigger configuration

Tags: tridion, smarttarget, fredhopper

I'd like to create a SmartTarget promotion based on a date we have made available.

If the supplied date is older than 4 weeks (supplied date <= Today - 4 weeks) the promotion should be shown.

I cannot see a way to configure this in SmartTarget and was wondering if this is possible?

Failing that I'm looking at building the variable such as 'DateIsOlderThan4Weeks' and configuring this as a boolean.

Before I do that, I thought it would be best to check if there is a more elegant solution as the customer may decide to implement similar logic based on other periods of elapsed time and it would be nice if they didn't need to ask a developer to add a bit of logic each time.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe that there is currently a way to perform a calculation on a trigger of a date base type. You just get the start/end/schedule options.

Instead of supplying a boolean trigger, and thereby (as you allude to) limiting the ability of promotion managers to alter the date difference, why not calculate the difference in days/weeks/months and supply those as number based triggers, i.e. SuppliedDateWeekDifference < 4? That would allow someone managing the promotion to change the values.

Comment: Hi David,  Thanks for your answer.   Indeed this is a very nice way to go, and having just done a POC and review the customer, they really like the way this works :)